# can std::forward takes std::function<void()> as the class type?

Tags: c++11

I've always seen std::forward being utilized as below, utilized inside a template function

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& arg): bar(std::forward<T>(arg)){}
```

Suppose I want to do this.

```
class A
{
private:
  std::function<void()> bar;
public:
  template<class T>
  A(T&& arg):
    bar(std::forward<T>(arg))
  {}
};
```

Since bar already has its type defined. I can also directly specify T as `std::function<void()> >`.

```
class A
{
private:
  std::function<void()> bar;
public:
  A(std::function<void()>&& arg):
    bar(std::forward<std::function<void()>>(arg))
  {}
};
```

Both would be ok to compile. However, the second realization only support `A(const std::function<void()>)`. While the first realization support `A(const std::function<void()>&)` and `A(std::function<void()>&&)` etc.

Comment: that is the initialization list.

Comment: it is not in a function. it is inside a class definition.

Comment: @sarah I (aggressively, in that I cannot be sure this is what you mean) edited your methods into constructors, as your `:` syntax implies.  Please try to post [MCVE]s in the future: compile your posted code and make sure that the error you get is an error you expect.  If I got it wrong, please revert my changes.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for the modification. Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to simplify my code, didn't realize the mismatch.

Comment: How is the compiler unhappy with the 2nd?  [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef35ec840001b8c)?

Comment: Error C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'A'...

Comment: @Sarah that error isn't produced by the code shown above.  [See, it compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef35ec840001b8c). This is why a [MCVE] is important!

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for the correction. Both are ok to compile. However, the second realization only support `A(const std::function<void()>)`. While the first realization support `A(const std::function<void()>&)` and `A(std::function<void()>&&)` etc. In this case, it would be beneficial to support template while using std::forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward is a conditional move of its argument.  It is almost equivalent to `std::move` if and only if the type passed to it is a value type or rvalue reference type.

A move is a cast to an rvalue reference.

If you pass a *different* type to `std::forward` than its argument type, it will do horrible things.  If convertible between, this would often involve creating a temporary within a function then returning a reference to it.

The proper thing to pass to `std::forward(x)` is `X`, where the type of `x` is `X&&`.  Anything else is going to be extremely quirky and advanced use, and will probably cause unexpected behavior...

In your case, [the second works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef35ec840001b8c), but is pointless.  As `std::forward` is a conditional move, and we are passing it a fixed type, we know it is a `std::move`.

So we should replace `std::forward<std::function<void()>>(arg)` with `std::move(arg)`, which is both clearer and more conventional.  Also, equivalent in this case.

Generally `std::forward` should only be used in cases where you are using forwarding references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my example, the two code samples both forward arg to bar, where bar is defined as std::function<void()>.
In the first realization, std::forward specifies a class type T, and the function is defined as template. 
In the second realization no longer pass type T, instead, it specifies the class type as std::function<void()>. 
In which case, do you think it is dangerous? The first or the second?

Comment: @Sarah it is not dangerous, which one to do depends on what you want. do you just want it to accept a `std::function` or accept anything that can be constructed into a `std::function`. I'd prefer the former because its more explicit and avoids more templates (edit: actually the latter is moot because none of the constructors for `std::function` are `explicit`)

Comment: @Sarah A, I misread your second one.  Funny because I edited it too.  Directly addressed it now.